# form_for nested attribute not updating in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form and it is supposed to update a nested attribute (the tenant(user) escrow model) I am having trouble getting the correct syntax.

_escrow_update_form.html.erb

> ```
> <%= form_for @tenant, url: tenants_escrow_path, method: :patch, validate: true do |a| %>   
>  <%= a.fields_for :escrow do |f| %>   
>   <%= f.label :new_amount_to_escrow %>
>   <%= f.number_field(:escrow_payment) %>
>  <% end %>
>   <%= a.submit("Done! Go back to the Dashboard", {class: "btn btn-success btn-lg", :id=> 'goalButton'}) %>
>
> <% end %>
> ```

escrow_controller

> ```
> def update
>  @tenant = current_tenant
>  if @tenant.escrows.update(escrow_params)
>     redirect_to tenants_dashboard_path, notice: "Your escrow payment informaton has been updated"
>  else
>     redirect_to tenants_escrow_path, notice: "Your escrow payment was not updated, try again"
>  end  
> private
>   def escrow_params
>     params.permit(:escrow_payment, :home_value, :total_saved)
>   end 
> end
> ```

routes.rb

```
namespace :tenants do
  resources :escrow
```

escrow model

```
class Escrow
  include Mongoid::Document

  #associations
  belongs_to :tenant
```

tenant model

```
class Tenant
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :escrow, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :escrow
```

The model will not update. It gives the error "undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass"

Which means `@tenant` does't have any `escrow`

In `_escrow_update_form.html.erb` build a `escrow` if `@tenant.escrow` is nil

```
<% escrow = @tenant.escrow ?  @tenant.escrow : @tenant.build_escrow %>
<%= form_for @tenant, url: tenants_escrow_path, method: :patch, validate: true do |a| %>   
 <%= a.fields_for :escrow, escrow do |f| %>   
  <%= f.label :new_amount_to_escrow %>
  <%= f.number_field(:escrow_payment) %>
 <% end %>
  <%= a.submit("Done! Go back to the Dashboard", {class: "btn btn-success btn-lg", :id=> 'goalButton'}) %>

<% end %>
```

In strong parameter whitelist  nested paramter

```
def update
 @tenant = current_tenant
 if @tenant.update(escrow_params) #updating @tenant will automatically update the corresponding escrow
    redirect_to tenants_dashboard_path, notice: "Your escrow payment informaton has been updated"
 else
    redirect_to tenants_escrow_path, notice: "Your escrow payment was not updated, try again"
 end
end
private
  def escrow_params
    params.require(:tenant).permit(:escrow_payment, :home_value, :total_saved, escrow_attributes: [])
  end 
end
```

Comment: Question: Is building the model in the view sugar syntax?

Comment: @SupremeA You can also build it in controller side. with conditionally.